# Splitting a 31m Plot into 1mile sections

Tags: set

I was hoping someone could help me.

I have a very large data set which represents the temperature & soil moisture of a coastline taken every 0.22 yards over a distance of 31 miles.

I am trying to create a series of plots where by a new plot is created for every 1 x mile along the x axis.

I am not sure how to achieve this, i am certain a loop is needed, the other issue i have is that i need a sub plot created one representing the temp and the other representing the soil moisture.

My thinking was something like:-

X, Y1, Y2 data stored in a dataframe
loop through the dataframe until the end is reached.
Start_Mile = 1st value in the Distance Column of the dataframe
End_Mile = loop through the X column until 1 x full mile
plot???

Can anyone help?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this will a loop.

I set the the x axis to a counter which measured distance.

Thanks.